# How to get id from react element

Tags: reactjs

I dont understand **why** i cant get the id from a react object...

```
    function OpenNav() {
document.getElementById('lateralNav').style.animation = 'MenuEntrar 0.5s';
}

    ReactDOM.render(
<div className="barra-lateral" id="lateralNav" onClick={OpenNav()}>
,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I know that im doing something wrong but i dont understand how to get the **id** to change the stile !
I already tried to use the script tag inside the html page but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your `onClick` must be like this :  `onClick={OpenNav}`

but i have better solution for your problem , and it is using [Refs in Reat](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

for example you can write your component like below :

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

export const MayNav = () => {
  const MyRef = useRef();

  function OpenNav() {
    MyRef.style.animation = "MenuEntrar 0.5s";
  }

  return <div onClick={OpenNav} ref={MyRef}></div>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! but imagine if i need to send some data like this => onClick={OpenNav('x10')}           How can i do it ?

Comment: then you shoud do it like this : onClick={()=>openNav('x10')}